# DC Air pump oscillator - square vs sine

Tags: oscillator

I have an air pump that currently runs on AC, but I want to run on a solar/battery system that's 12V DC. The internals of the pump include a transformer to reduce voltage from 120 (I haven't been able to test the output voltage yet). From there, there is a magnet which powers a lever that squeezes a bellow. The magnet appears to go back and forth based on the oscillation of the AC current.

So my question is, if I were to remove the circuitry and power the magnets directly, could I get away with a square wave oscillator? Or could that somehow be damaging to the components that should use a sine wave oscillation instead?

Comment: This will be a 60hz oscillation to match the current 60hz AC input.

Comment: My gut feeling is that you can probably get away with a square wave for this type of pump.  The possible side effects that I can think of: more acoustic noise, reduced life time of the bellows.

Comment: A far more interesting question might be if you can get away with unidirectional drive - likely you can at least to a degree, though one polarity may work better than the other.  But you may need a step up transformer or to rewind the coil for a lower voltage - the original almost certainly does not have a "transformer" but rather a similar-looking coil that operates directly off the line voltage.

Answer (score 1):

I'm imagining this to be a low-volume reciprocating pump like those used for aerating aquariums?

If so then you may be better off just replacing the air pump with one that uses a 12V DC motor. These are commonly available, such as here http://www.robotshop.com/en/sfe-air-pump.html and http://www.ebay.com/itm/12V-DC-micro-Diaphragm-Drain-pump-Pumping-air-pump-for-aquarium-drinking-water-/171122685480?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item27d7b4f628.

Answer (score 0):

Many Dc pumps tend to use a brushed motor that has a reduced life expectancy by design.
I love the reliability of ac pumps like the tetra aquarium pumps they sell pump service kits for the diaphragms for only 18$. Instead of tossing a 80$ DC pump as it reaches the failure point.

Tetras design is a simple electro magnet powered level bouncing between and pushing on two rubber diaphragms
I'm planning to build a oscillating circuit with a 555 timer and MOSFETs to produce a AC voltage to drive it